# User Field Level Security behavior with a Workflow Email Alert using a custom Visualforce page

Tags: workflow, email-alert, visualforce-template

I'm currently having an issue with a custom Visualforce email template not displaying a field value when sent. This email is sent using from a Workflow rule assigned to an Email alert. Considering this page in the documentation, they are all ran as system administrator:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000193423&language=en_US

> This is expected behavior. An email template which is sent by Workflow/Approval automation will populate all merge fields in the template (provided there is available data for those fields), regardless of the Field Level Security of the user who causes the email to be sent.

Right now, when I trigger that workflow rule with a user who doesn't have access to the specific field, it is not included in the email sent. If I do execute that workflow as a system administrator, it does contain the field value.

Am I missing something? Is it because it is using a custom Visualforce email template? I thought EVERY email sent from a Workflow Email Alert WOULD skip field level security, but it seems in this case that it is applying the settings of the active user triggering the workflow rule. Is it because the email is rendered by the active user before being sent?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find anything out about this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Same here. been running in circles around this. any chance you had this solved?